# The same GameObject accessible by two players in Unity Networking (UNT)

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer, unity-networking

Anyone know, or have some ideas, how to have a GameObject in Unity3D Multiplayer (UNT) that is accessible for two player. What i want to do is to have an object that can be dragged from both players.

I have been looking at tutorials and read documentation but have not yet figured out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple workaround, I made three GOs (one that is being moved (main one), and two GOs that just receive informations from two players). When one player drags main GO on their screen their GO sends info to corresponding GO on other screen, it receives information and moves the main GO, same thing happens with another player. (I did this in Photon)

Most of the multiplayer engines don't support two way communication, so you have to create two one way communications to simulate one two way communication.

Comment: Could you provide a few more details how you did this?

Comment: Sure, make all movement of your MainGO go through player's let's call it UpdateGO, make UpdateGO network gameObject so each player has it's own and have each player have it's own version of MainGO. Write a method in UpdateGO something like this

Vector3 toMove;
void moveBy(Vector3 amount){ 
   mainGO.Translate(amount);
   toMove += amount;
}

Whenever you want to move MainGO call this method and whenever you send that from this GO set toMove to Vector3.zero, and when you get values on the other end just move the MainGO on that end by received amount.